# Install suggestions?

Tags: install, composer

This happens on every install (see below suggestions) via Composer on a MAMP Pro stack, running PHP 7.1, Mysql 5.7 & Composer 1.7.2.

Albeit suggestions, could this affect the performance or plugin compatibility of a base install?

```
server:lab user$ composer create-project craftcms/craft .
Installing craftcms/craft (1.0.36)
  - Installing craftcms/craft (1.0.36): Loading from cache
Created project in .
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 50 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing craftcms/plugin-installer (1.5.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing yiisoft/yii2-composer (2.0.7): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-ctype (v1.9.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-mbstring (v1.9.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing twig/twig (v2.5.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing enshrined/svg-sanitize (0.9.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing danielstjules/stringy (3.1.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing zendframework/zend-stdlib (3.2.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing zendframework/zend-escaper (2.6.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing doctrine/lexer (v1.0.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing egulias/email-validator (2.1.6): Loading from cache
  - Installing swiftmailer/swiftmailer (v6.1.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer (2.1.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/process (v3.3.6): Loading from cache
  - Installing yiisoft/yii2 (2.0.15.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing yiisoft/yii2-debug (2.0.14): Loading from cache
  - Installing yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap (2.0.8): Loading from cache
  - Installing zendframework/zend-feed (2.10.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing craftcms/cms (3.0.25): Loading from cache
  - Installing yiisoft/yii2-queue (2.1.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing true/punycode (v2.1.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing seld/cli-prompt (1.0.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing pixelandtonic/imagine (v0.7.1.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing mikehaertl/php-shellcommand (1.4.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing paragonie/random_compat (v2.0.17): Loading from cache
  - Installing guzzlehttp/promises (v1.3.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing psr/http-message (1.0.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing guzzlehttp/psr7 (1.4.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing guzzlehttp/guzzle (6.3.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing league/oauth2-client (2.3.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing league/flysystem (1.0.47): Loading from cache
  - Installing elvanto/litemoji (1.4.4): Loading from cache
  - Installing creocoder/yii2-nested-sets (0.9.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing craftcms/server-check (1.1.6): Loading from cache
  - Installing craftcms/oauth2-craftid (1.0.0.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/finder (v3.3.6): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/filesystem (v3.3.6): Loading from cache
  - Installing psr/log (1.0.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/debug (v3.3.6): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/console (v3.3.6): Loading from cache
  - Installing seld/phar-utils (1.0.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing seld/jsonlint (1.7.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing justinrainbow/json-schema (5.2.7): Loading from cache
  - Installing composer/spdx-licenses (1.4.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing composer/semver (1.4.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing composer/ca-bundle (1.1.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing composer/composer (1.6.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing cebe/markdown (1.1.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing ezyang/htmlpurifier (v4.10.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing vlucas/phpdotenv (v2.5.1): Loading from cache
zendframework/zend-feed suggests installing zendframework/zend-cache (Zend\Cache component, for optionally caching feeds between requests)
zendframework/zend-feed suggests installing zendframework/zend-db (Zend\Db component, for use with PubSubHubbub)
zendframework/zend-feed suggests installing zendframework/zend-http (Zend\Http for PubSubHubbub, and optionally for use with Zend\Feed\Reader)
zendframework/zend-feed suggests installing zendframework/zend-servicemanager (Zend\ServiceManager component, for easily extending ExtensionManager implementations)
zendframework/zend-feed suggests installing zendframework/zend-validator (Zend\Validator component, for validating email addresses used in Atom feeds and entries when using the Writer subcomponent)
craftcms/cms suggests installing ext-imagick (Adds support for more image processing formats and options.)
yiisoft/yii2-queue suggests installing yiisoft/yii2-redis (Need for Redis queue.)
yiisoft/yii2-queue suggests installing pda/pheanstalk (Need for Beanstalk queue.)
yiisoft/yii2-queue suggests installing php-amqplib/php-amqplib (Need for AMQP queue.)
yiisoft/yii2-queue suggests installing enqueue/amqp-lib (Need for AMQP interop queue.)
yiisoft/yii2-queue suggests installing ext-gearman (Need for Gearman queue.)
yiisoft/yii2-queue suggests installing aws/aws-sdk-php (Need for aws SQS.)
pixelandtonic/imagine suggests installing ext-imagick (to use the Imagick implementation)
pixelandtonic/imagine suggests installing ext-gmagick (to use the Gmagick implementation)
paragonie/random_compat suggests installing ext-libsodium (Provides a modern crypto API that can be used to generate random bytes.)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-aws-s3-v2 (Allows you to use S3 storage with AWS SDK v2)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3 (Allows you to use S3 storage with AWS SDK v3)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-azure (Allows you to use Windows Azure Blob storage)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-cached-adapter (Flysystem adapter decorator for metadata caching)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-eventable-filesystem (Allows you to use EventableFilesystem)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-rackspace (Allows you to use Rackspace Cloud Files)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-sftp (Allows you to use SFTP server storage via phpseclib)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-webdav (Allows you to use WebDAV storage)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-ziparchive (Allows you to use ZipArchive adapter)
league/flysystem suggests installing spatie/flysystem-dropbox (Allows you to use Dropbox storage)
league/flysystem suggests installing srmklive/flysystem-dropbox-v2 (Allows you to use Dropbox storage for PHP 5 applications)
symfony/console suggests installing symfony/event-dispatcher ()
Writing lock file
Generating optimized autoload files
> @php -r "copy('.env.example', '.env');"
> @php -r "unlink('composer.json');"
> @php -r "unlink('LICENSE.md');"
> @php -r "unlink('README.md');"
> @php -r "rename('composer.json.default', 'composer.json');"
Generating optimized autoload files
> @php craft setup/welcome

   ______ .______          ___       _______ .___________.
  /      ||   _  \        /   \     |   ____||           |
 |  ,----'|  |_)  |      /  ^  \    |  |__   `---|  |----`
 |  |     |      /      /  /_\  \   |   __|      |  |
 |  `----.|  |\  \----./  _____  \  |  |         |  |
  \______|| _| `._____/__/     \__\ |__|         |__|

     A       N   E   W       I   N   S   T   A   L   L
               ______ .___  ___.      _______.
              /      ||   \/   |     /       |
             |  ,----'|  \  /  |    |   (----`
             |  |     |  |\/|  |     \   \
             |  `----.|  |  |  | .----)   |
              \______||__|  |__| |_______/



Generating a security key ... done (iD6CQCDo8OEpF36qGnPPcylYpCI9gGz6)

Welcome to Craft CMS! Run the following command if you want to setup Craft from your terminal:

    ~/Studio/clients/lab/craft setup
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you mean the `suggests installing` part? If so, these are just optional packages that add optional features. I wouldn't sweat it, especially in local dev.